# Fluent NHibernate. Do I need to re-create the database when changing Cascade options?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm wondering...

1. Do I need to re-create the database, when changing Cascade options inside my mapping classes ?
2. What mapping options physically affects the database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need. The cascade option are controlled by nhibernate, not by the database.
2. Well, only the mappings that affects tables/columns/index/constraints structures.